# What is the purpose of “ce qui”?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, pronoms-relatifs

Someone said this to me in a message recently and I don't understand what they are trying to say (they are native French).

> Je vais postuler à l'étranger ce qui va me permettre de...

"I am going to apply to the foreign that which is going to permit me to..." is what I read...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*À l'étranger* means **abroad**, which is the only part you haven't translated correctly. So

> Je vais postuler a l'étranger ce qui va me permettre de [...]

could become

> I will apply abroad, which will allow me to [...]